# What is the best way to report a bug/feature request discussed here to Apple?

Tags: macos, ios, preview, bug

If a question asked on this forum does not get an answer because the feature requested does not exist (e.g. [1]), or it is agreed that there is a bug, ... what is the best way to report this to Apple?

This forum does I have found help in phrasing the question and problem, and if enough time has elapsed helps to reveal the limits of the understanding of a knowledgeable community on a topic. A question posed and edited here should therfore be very valuable to Apple.

So can one link to a description here and send it to Apple? And where would one send it? Or do they follow what is going on here so that there is no need to do that?

PS. I think it may be useful to have a tag for issues relating to how to submit issues to apple. Eg. bug-reports or something like that.

[1] For example: [Does Preview.app's freehand tool allow one to select multiple shapes easily?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322624/does-preview-apps-freehand-tool-allow-one-to-select-multiple-shapes-easily)

Comment: I feel like this is a meta question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple does not *officially* follow what goes on here. It's not an Apple site per se, and while there are users on this site that happen to work for Apple, they do not represent Apple in their interactions here.

The absolute best way to provide feedback to Apple is to use [Apple's feedback page](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

This gives you a range of options from which you can select the product or service you want to provide feedback about. Once you select the option you want you'll be taken to a form and from there you can select the type of feedback you wish to provide, including bug reports and enhancement requests (among others).

Depending on the product you've chosen, you'll also have the option of selecting the relevant version of macOS, iOS, etc.

Finally, as an aside, you may be interested in this meta post: [Discourage "suggest to Apple" or "report to Apple" answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3157/168832)

Answer (score 4):

Apple offers a Feedback Page for that: https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: Unfortunately there's no option for every app (Preview for example), I suppose just pick the app you find closest to that..

Comment: Ah good, that answers the Where. (It looks like that Apple feedback page is a lot more organised than it used to be). The other question was, can one send them a link to here, or are they not allowed to follow links perhaps? (There was a time, when that was a problem I think) I suppose I could add as a question: can one add links to issues here in the crash reports that one can send when an app goes down in flames?

Comment: Apps without a specific option should be reported under the MacOS version you are using.

Comment: @HenryStory  As far as I know there is no problem providing links in the feedback channel to posting elsewhere.  I think it is often necessary to do that because space in the feedback form is limited.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a **bug** (or a feature request, but only if it relates to developer tools or APIs) and you have an Apple developer account, you can [submit a bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

> Apple Bug Reporter is a web-based tool that developers can use to
>   report issues with Apple software and services, request enhancements
>   to APIs and tools, and track the status of their feedback. To access
>   Apple Bug Reporter, sign in with the Apple ID associated with your
>   developer account.

According to [this Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8796) post, this is an interface to Apple's RADAR bug tracking system.

Comment: that is probably the one I have used in the past -  a pretty long time ago, as Apple was still supporting Java.